# Fatal error: Class WP_Customize_Image_Control not found

Tags: theme-development, theme-customizer

I'm using WAMP on Windows 8.1 64 bits to develop a custom theme.

Right now, I'm getting the following errors when trying to create a custom control with the `WP_Customize_Image_Control` class:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Ivana\Api\Customizer\WP_Customize_Image_Control' not found in C:\wamp64\www\ivana-5.2\wp-content\themes\ivana\inc\Api\Customizer\FeaturedCategories.php on line 115
>
> Error: Class 'Ivana\Api\Customizer\WP_Customize_Image_Control' not found in C:\wamp64\www\ivana-5.2\wp-content\themes\ivana\inc\Api\Customizer\FeaturedCategories.php on line 115

I'm using an object oriented design, got from this starter theme: https://github.com/Alecaddd/awps

inc/Api/Customizer.php
    namespace Ivana\Api;

```
class Customizer
{
    public function register()
    {
        add_action( 'customize_register', [ $this, 'setup' ] );
    }

    public function get_classes()
    {
        return [
            Customizer\FeaturedCategories::class
        ];
    }

    public function setup( $wp_customize )
    {
        foreach ( $this->get_classes() as $class )
        {

            if ( method_exists( $class, 'register' ) )
            {
                $service = new $class;

                $service->register( $wp_customize );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

inc/Api/Customizer/FeaturedCategories.php

```
namespace Ivana\Api\Customizer;

use Ivana\Helpers;

class FeaturedCategories
{
    public function register( $wp_customize )
    {
        $this->add_panels( $wp_customize );
        $this->add_sections( $wp_customize );
        $this->add_settings( $wp_customize );
        $this->add_controls( $wp_customize );
    }

    private function add_panels( $wp_customize )
    {
        $wp_customize->add_panel( 'featured_categories', [
            'title' => 'Featured Categories',
            'description' => 'I\'m looking for a good placeholder',
            'priority' => 100
        ] );
    }

    private function add_sections( $wp_customize )
    {
        $wp_customize->add_section( 'featured_category_0', [
            'title' => 'Featured Category 1',
            'panel' => 'featured_categories',
            'description' => 'Highlight categories on your front page.'
        ] );

        $wp_customize->add_section( 'featured_category_1', [
            'title' => 'Featured Category 2',
            'panel' => 'featured_categories',
            'description' => 'Highlight categories on your front page.'
        ] );

        $wp_customize->add_section( 'featured_category_2', [
            'title' => 'Featured Category 3',
            'panel' => 'featured_categories',
            'description' => 'Highlight categories on your front page.'
        ] );
    }

    private function add_settings( $wp_customize )
    {
        $wp_customize->add_setting( 'category_slug_0', [
            'default' => '',
            'transport' => 'postMessage',
            'sanitize_callback' => 'wp_filter_nohtml_kses'
        ] );

        $wp_customize->add_setting( 'category_slug_1', [
            'default' => '',
            'transport' => 'postMessage',
            'sanitize_callback' => 'wp_filter_nohtml_kses'
        ] );

        $wp_customize->add_setting( 'category_slug_2', [
            'default' => '',
            'transport' => 'postMessage',
            'sanitize_callback' => 'wp_filter_nohtml_kses'
        ] );

        $wp_customize->add_setting( 'category_image_0', [
            'default' => '',
            'transport' => 'postMessage',
            'sanitize_callback' => 'wp_filter_nohtml_kses'
        ] );

        $wp_customize->add_setting( 'category_image_1', [
            'default' => '',
            'transport' => 'postMessage',
            'sanitize_callback' => 'wp_filter_nohtml_kses'
        ] );

        $wp_customize->add_setting( 'category_image_2', [
            'default' => '',
            'transport' => 'postMessage',
            'sanitize_callback' => 'wp_filter_nohtml_kses'
        ] );
    }

    private function add_controls( $wp_customize )
    {
        // var_dump( $wp_customize );
        // echo $wp_customize->registered_control_types;

        $wp_customize->add_control( 'category_slug_2', [
            'section' => 'featured_category_0',
            'label' => 'Category slug',
            // 'description' => 'Not the animal',
            'type' => 'text'
        ] );

        $wp_customize->add_control( 'category_slug_1', [
            'section' => 'featured_category_1',
            'label' => 'Category slug',
            // 'description' => 'Not the animal',
            'type' => 'text'
        ] );

        $wp_customize->add_control( 'category_slug_0', [
            'section' => 'featured_category_2',
            'label' => 'Category slug',
            // 'description' => 'Not the animal',
            'type' => 'text'
        ] );

        $wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Image_Control( $wp_customize, 'category_image_2', [
            'section' => 'featured_category_0',
            'label' => 'Featured Category Image 1'
        ] ) );
    }
}
```

Why is WordPress unable to find the `WP_Customize_Image_Control` class, or any of those classes, for that matter? (Also tried with color and media with no success).

If you see Customizer.php, the register method is calling the `'customize_register'` action, and setup receives `$wp_customize.`

This works perfectly if not trying to use custom controls.

Comment: By directly using the Customizer API in the functions.php class, everything works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by adding `use WP_Customize_Image_Control;` to inc\Customizer\FeaturedCategories.php:

```
namespace Ivana\Api\Customizer;

    use WP_Customize_Image_Control;
use Ivana\Helpers;

class FeaturedCategories
{
    public function register( $wp_customize )
    {
        $this->add_panels( $wp_customize );
        $this->add_sections( $wp_customize );
        $this->add_settings( $wp_customize );
        $this->add_controls( $wp_customize );
    }

    public function add_panels( $wp_customize )
    {
        $wp_customize->add_panel( 'featured_categories', [
            'title' => 'Featured Categories',
            'description' => 'I\'m looking for a lady',
            'priority' => 100
        ] );
    }

    public function add_sections( $wp_customize )
    {
        $wp_customize->add_section( 'featured_category_0', [
            'title' => 'Featured Category 1',
            'panel' => 'featured_categories',
            'description' => 'Highlight categories on your front page.'
        ] );

        $wp_customize->add_section( 'featured_category_1', [
            'title' => 'Featured Category 2',
            'panel' => 'featured_categories',
            'description' => 'Highlight categories on your front page.'
        ] );

        $wp_customize->add_section( 'featured_category_2', [
            'title' => 'Featured Category 3',
            'panel' => 'featured_categories',
            'description' => 'Highlight categories on your front page.'
        ] );
    }

    public function add_settings( $wp_customize )
    {
        $wp_customize->add_setting( 'category_slug_0', [
            'default' => '',
            'transport' => 'postMessage',
            'sanitize_callback' => 'wp_filter_nohtml_kses'
        ] );

        $wp_customize->add_setting( 'category_slug_1', [
            'default' => '',
            'transport' => 'postMessage',
            'sanitize_callback' => 'wp_filter_nohtml_kses'
        ] );

        $wp_customize->add_setting( 'category_slug_2', [
            'default' => '',
            'transport' => 'postMessage',
            'sanitize_callback' => 'wp_filter_nohtml_kses'
        ] );

        $wp_customize->add_setting( 'category_image_0', [
            'default' => '',
            'transport' => 'postMessage',
            'sanitize_callback' => 'wp_filter_nohtml_kses'
        ] );

        $wp_customize->add_setting( 'category_image_1', [
            'default' => '',
            'transport' => 'postMessage',
            'sanitize_callback' => 'wp_filter_nohtml_kses'
        ] );

        $wp_customize->add_setting( 'category_image_2', [
            'default' => '',
            'transport' => 'postMessage',
            'sanitize_callback' => 'wp_filter_nohtml_kses'
        ] );
    }

    public function add_controls( $wp_customize )
    {
        $wp_customize->add_control( 'category_slug_2', [
            'section' => 'featured_category_0',
            'label' => 'Category slug',
            // 'description' => 'Not the animal',
            'type' => 'text'
        ] );

        $wp_customize->add_control( 'category_slug_1', [
            'section' => 'featured_category_1',
            'label' => 'Category slug',
            // 'description' => 'Not the animal',
            'type' => 'text'
        ] );

        $wp_customize->add_control( 'category_slug_0', [
            'section' => 'featured_category_2',
            'label' => 'Category slug',
            // 'description' => 'Not the animal',
            'type' => 'text'
        ] );

        $wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Image_Control( $wp_customize, 'category_image_2', [
            'section' => 'featured_category_0',
            'label' => 'Featured Category Image 1'
        ] ) );
    }
}
```

I found the solution by copying and pasting the Customizer classes from the source code of the mentioned theme (AWPS): https://github.com/Alecaddd/awps/blob/master/inc/Api/Customizer/Footer.php

Comment: The issue wasthat you're attempting to use the `WP_Customize_Image_Control` class in a file that was namespaced. The `WP_Customize_Image_Control` class is not part of your namespace, so you either need to use `use WP_Customize_Image_Control;` or prepend each use of the class with \, like `\WP_Customize_Image_Control`.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying the actual reason for why this works and for adding the solution of prepending the \.